# Java: pass parameter in constructor or method?

Tags: java, constructor

Currently I have a class, `TransactionData`, which is just a little bit more than a POJO. I build the object from an `HTTPServletRequest`. What I do:

```
public class TransactionData
{

    // ...

    public TransactionData(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        // do actual work here
    }

}
```

There many WTF here, the most disturbing one is that the object `TransactionData` is tightly coupled to `HTTPServletRequest`. What I thought: create an interface, `TransactionDataExtractor`, with an `extract()` method, so that I might implement different classes to build the object.

```
public interface TransactionDataExtractor
{
    public TransactionData extract();
}
```

But how do I pass the stuff needed to build the TransactionData to every implementation? The firt thing that came to mind was to use the different constructors, like this:

```
public class TransactionDataExtractorRequest implements TransactionDataExtractor
{
    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    public TransactionDataExtractorRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest)
    {
        this.httpRequest = httpRequest;
    }

    public TransactionData extract()
    {
        // do whatever is required
    }

}
```

But in this case whenever I need to build a new TransactionData object I have to create a new TransactionDataExtractorRequest. An implicit dependency I don't like at all.
The other alternative I could think of was passing an Object parameter to `extract()` and cast it whenever required, giving up the type safety and introducing a lot of boiler plate ugly code

```
    public TransactionData extract(Object o)
    {
        HttpServletRequest h;
        if (o instanceof HttpServletRequest)
        {
             h = (HttpServletRequest)o;
        } 
        //...
    }
```

I don't know if I have made myself clear. I do feel like I'm missing something, I know the solution is very simple but I can't get hold of it.
Any thoughts?
TIA.

EDIT: the problem might even be that my hunch is completely wrong and I may dismiss it without any regret

Comment: What's wrong with having a dependency on `HttpServletRequest`?  Assuming this class is meant to be used as part of some sort of webapp that seems like a completely reasonable dependency to have, to me.

Comment: The TransactionData is part of a complex protocol; part of the transmission is handled by a servlet, but other parts of the infrastructure (the unit tests, for example, or the client) are agnostic to HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Still not entirely convinced this is necessary, but see if my answer below is of any help.

Comment: I start to feel that aroth and Stephen C are indeed right: this kind of coupling really is not to be a concern. I accepted axtavt answer, though, because it encouraged me to try something I don't do often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your only problem is ensuring type safety when passing the source object to `extract()`, you can use generics:

```
public interface TransactionDataExtractor<E> {
    public TransactionData extract(E source); 
} 

public class TransactionDataExtractorRequest 
    implements TransactionDataExtractor<HttpServletRequest> {
    public TransactionData extract(HttpServletRequest source) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer; I admit I generally still don't use the generics as much as I would need/like to, maybe it's about time.

Answer (score 3):

> I do feel like I'm missing something ... Any thoughts?

Well my thought is that you are attempting to solve a problem that isn't really a problem.  There's no obvious (to me) reason why the coupling you are trying to get rid of is actually harmful.  Certainly, your attempts to remove the coupling are not making the code any easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

In case you rely on request parameters only, you can get `request.getParameterMap()` and use the `Map` instead. (if you need headers - `getHeaders()`)

Answer (score 1):

Creating/reusing a `TransactionDataExtractorRequest` instance isn't a problem, IMHO. You'd need to somewhere distinguish between the parameter types anyway and if you decouple TransactionData and the parameter types by using some sort of factory, what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not convinced that much is gained by removing the dependency on `HttpServletRequest`, but I would suggest something along the lines of:

```
public class TransactionData {
    public TransactionData(TransactionDataOptions options) throws IOException {
        // do actual work here
    }
}

//TransactionData wants some state that it currently gets from a HttpServletRequest,
//figure out what that state is, and abstract an interface for accessing it
public interface TransactionDataOptions {
    //getters for things that TransactionData needs
}

//take all the code that pulls state out of the HttpServletRequest, and move it here
public class TransactionDataHttpOptions implements TransactionDataOptions {
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    //getter implementations that pull the required information out of the request

    public TransactionDataHttpOptions(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
}

//now you can also do this, and use TransactionData even without a HttpServletRequest
public class TransactionDataMapOptions implements TransactionDataOptions {
    private Map<String, Object> map;

    //getter implementations that pull the required information out of the map

    public TransactionDataHttpOptions(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

If you go this route, then `TransactionDataHttpOptions` is the only object with a dependency on `HttpServletRequest`.  And since it is basically a wrapper that is intended to work with a `HttpServletRequest` I think that should be fine.